# JS Prototype, capturing spacebar keycode unsupported?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
function observeingKeys() {
    console.log('watching keys now!');
    $(document).observe('keypress', function(event){
    switch (event.keyCode) {
            case Event.KEY_UP:
                console.log('Up');      
            break;
            case Event.KEY_RIGHT:
                console.log('Right');
            break;
            case Event.KEY_DOWN:
                console.log('Down');
            break;
            case Event.KEY_LEFT:
                console.log('Left');
            break;
            case 32: //Space
                console.log('Space')
            break;
            case 13: //Return
                console.log('Return')
            break;
     }
    });
 }
```

Here we are. First of all there is no "KEY_SPACE" or anything like that in the prototype framework, so the use of the actual keycode is unavoidable. In this case, the keycode for space is 32.

The code works for every case except for space.
Am I missing something or is it just not supported?

Comment: are you using any js libraries?

Comment: @Neal he specifies Prototype framework

Comment: have you added a breakpoint in the observe callback and hit the spacebar to see if it is triggered at all?

Comment: The spacebar event fires fine for me in jsfiddle using your code (http://jsfiddle.net/CQsyL/)

Comment: @Matt Cant say that I know how to use jsfiddle.net and yes the spacebar doesnt even trigger it.

Comment: What browser are you using? It works fine for me in Chrome 12

Comment: works in Chrome for me aswell! but still not in FF4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that while FireFox4 uses keyCode for those other key events, for the Space Bar, it sets event.keyCode to 0, but event.charCode to 32.

EDIT: In fact, it appears that for most keys it uses charCode, but for some reason, on a few, such as Enter, it uses keyCode.